# Git push with a specific user/pass

Tags: git, push

I configured my local repository to use SSH (shared server), but I want to push with my specific git account. How can I do that? Is it possible to pass some extra argument to use another authentication than the default?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure `~/.ssh/config` to have a section for the git server:

```
Host github.com
User git
IdentityFile /home/myname/.ssh/id_rsa_my_github_private_key
```

and then in your repository's `.git/config` have

```
[remote "github"]
url = git@github.com:myname/myrepository.git
…
```

HTH

Comment: What do you mean by `id_rsa_my_github_private_key`?

Comment: Okay, I guess that's just the name of the id_rsa file.

Comment: yup, but you can have one for each server you need to connect to. Whether it's your own gitlab, gerrit, gitolite, or cloud ones like github, gitorious, googlecode, bitbucket… You'll need one key for each of them!

Comment: Actually, my issue is that I **don't want to use the SSH auth to push** but my own account, so basically enter my login/password.

Comment: The SSH is here only to allow to pull, but is not allowed to push anything or change something on the remote server.